# can I change an app's language based on an iOS Device's default language?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have Created one simple in-house app for ipads. I would like to have 2 language for that app. Based on ipad default language App language should be same as ipad default language.

I tried to goggling it but didn't find proper answer.

Is it possible?
How can I do that?
Any Links, examples any documents?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is [a good starting point](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/) for internationalization and localization resources for iOS apps.

Comment: -1; Benoit, you've been here long enough to know that ["link only" answers aren't the best answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann The question is incredibly vague and isn't particularly answerable in its current state. The OP claims to have not been able to find any documentation or resources to the information. The link I provide is a good starting point. I still think it's better to leave my link up if anyone else finds the question and doesn't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TSLanguageManager](https://github.com/tonisalae/TSLanguageManager) SDK in order to do that. In basic, you define different string for each languages. Then the SDK checks your language and converts your defined strings/view elements into that language string. Also, you can switch between language by using this SDK in your app.